# IIS URL Rewrite Module : Redirect Based On QueryString

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I Have some problems with redirecting to another URL based on the query string parameters. I want to redirect users which enter www.domain.com/signup.aspx?p=1 to:

www.domain.com/signup

```
<rule name="Signup Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="signup\.aspx\?p=1" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="signup" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

Now when they enter www.domain.com/signup.aspx?p=2 they must go to:

www.domain.com/signup/promocode

```
<rule name="Signup Redirect 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="signup\.aspx\?p=2" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="signup/promocode" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

The above rules don't work. What is the right way to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Gr

Martijn

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See if this works a bit better:

```
<rule name="Signup Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="signup\.aspx$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p=1" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="signup" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>

<rule name="Signup Redirect 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="signup\.aspx$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p=2" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="signup/promocode" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 41):

A more robust method of using a value to select a destination is to use Rewrite Maps. The map is essentially a lookup table. This doesn't require a new rule (and an additional evaluation of the URL against a pattern on every request) for every new path.

```
<rules>
  <rule name="Signup Redirect Map" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^signup\.aspx$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p=([^&amp;]+)" />
      <add input="{Signups:{C:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:2}" redirectType="Temporary" />
  </rule>
</rules>
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="Signups">
    <add key="1" value="signup" />
    <add key="2" value="signup/promocode" />
    <add key="3" value="signup/newcode" />
    <add key="n" value="signup/futureproof" />
  </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Definitions:

- {C:1} is a backreference to the first condition match: the query string value.
- {Signups:{C:1}} is an instruction to look up {C:1} in the Signups map.
- {C:2} is a backreference to the second condition match: the value from the Signups map.