# IIS7 url rewrite issue when having "?"

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a URL in the format

```
abc/pqr/xyz/?word1
```

and this needs to redirect to

```
abc/pqr/xyz/?word2
```

Is is possible to do using IIS7 rewrite?

Comment: You want to rewrite the query string??

Comment: @cheesemacfly Yes, a category of information on our site has been changed, so this whole querystring needs to be redirected for anyone who's bookmarked old links. Obviously, we're fixing any links in our site already, the redirect is just so that old links don't break :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using the IIS7 rewrite module with the following rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite querystring" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^abc/pqr/xyz/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^word1$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?word2" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

What it does is: check that the url is `abc/pqr/xyz/` or `abc/pqr/xyz` and the query string exactly `word1`. If yes, it redirects the user to the same url (`{R:0}`) but appending `?word2` instead.

It is important to have the `appendQueryString="false"` option as you don't want the module to append your `word1` at the end.

By default, if not specified, the redirect is a 301 (permanent), that, regarding @Owen comment, seems to be the best fit for your case!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257403/iis-url-rewrite-module-redirect-based-on-querystring)

You need to specify the url to match, " abc/pqr/xyz", then the query string to match and replace.

Comment: Just doesnt seem to work at all. This is my code in web.config
<!-- language: c# -->
<rule name="Signup Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="/abc/(.+)/xyz/$" />
<conditions>
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(word1)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="/abc/\1/xyz/\?word2"/>
</rule>

Comment: IIS uses exact RegEx pattern matching.  I'm not 100% on this, but your match url might need to have the trailing '/' removed for the match to succeed.