# How to rewrite the url of a webpage in IIS UrlRewriteModule with web.config?

Tags: php, html, iis, seo, web-config

I search for a rule (or a set of rules) that eliminate the extensions of the html files
but at the same time to be able to rewrite the browser url like the example below:

category1_pageid2.html to categories_page (more seo friendly)

I have a shared hosting environment with IIS 8.5 with IIS_UrlRewriteModule 7.1.1952.0

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Does it need to support an array of words to convert from singular to plural (e.g. *category* to *categories*) or just that one instance?

Comment: Βy an array of words you mean multiple pages ? If yes Sam do you have an web.config example of how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS, I created a new rule:

[image]

Then in the next dialog, I added a **Pattern** *categories_page* with conditions for `{QUERY_STRING}` matching pattern `c=(\d+)&p=(\d+)` (though you may not need a query string - customize per your needs). And for the **Action** I added a *Rewrite URL* of `category{C:1}_pageid{C:2}.html`. If you don't need the query string, then you can un-check that checkbox for *append query string*.

[image]
[image]

Looking at the *web.config* file for the site, I see the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="category-page">
                    <match url="categories_page" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="category{C:1}_pageid{C:2}.html" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="c=(\d+)&amp;p=(\d+)" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When trying this in my browser, I see the category1_pageid2.html page when I naveigate to `localhost/categories_page?c=1&p=2`:

[image]

Other options include a [rewrite map](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257403/iis-url-rewrite-module-redirect-based-on-querystring#answer-3322091) for a short explanation.

Comment: Many many thanks for your detailed answer Sam. One last question...Is that possible is a shared hosting environment ? I cannot create an inbound rule in IIS 8.5 because I don't have the rights to access IIS administration. Does the web.config can work without the creating the inbound rule ?

Comment: I actually haven't tried it in a shared hosting environment, so I am not sure. I know the UI dialog listed _inbound rule_ but the xml in the *web.config* file doesn't contain that keyword so I think it should be okay... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯